# The 'Hide Top Bar' extension says 'The extension is incompatible with current GNOME version'. What do I do?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, extension, autohide

I recently upgraded to ubuntu 22.04 (jammy). Everything works fine except when I cannot toggle 'hide-top-bar' because it says 'The exention is incompatible with the current GNOME version'. I looked at my GNOME version and it is, as far as I could figure out, installed in its current version (GNOME shell 42.5).

What could be preventing me from toggling hide-top-bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: use `Just Perfection` extension instead, or any other extension has the function to toggle display top-bar and support Ubuntu 22.04. You can simply search for and install `Extension Manager` from Ubuntu Software, and use it to search extensions.

Option 2: try disabling extension version validation, though it may still not working. To do so, run command:

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell disable-extension-version-validation true`

Comment: Thank You. I used Just Perfection. I didn't know it existed.